Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17 || ^18 || ^19" from react-hook-form@7.53.1
I am getting this error while installing react-hook-form in my Next.js app.
npm resolution error report

While resolving: carepulse@0.1.0
Found: react@19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021
node_modules/react
react@"19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17 || ^18 || ^19" from react-hook-form@7.53.1
node_modules/react-hook-form
react-hook-form@"*" from the root project
peer react-hook-form@"^7.0.0" from @hookform/resolvers@3.9.0
node_modules/@hookform/resolvers
@hookform/resolvers@"*" from the root project

I tried using
npx shadcn@latest add form --force
and
npx shadcn@latest add form --legacy-peer-deps

But it keeps on showing 'unknown option'

Why didn't the react hook form update and fix this issue!!

I fixed this issue by downgrading my React version.
I replaced
    "react": "19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021"

from my nextJS package.json dependencies with
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"


and did "npm install" to update the dependencies.
The article below was helpful
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-version

Just in case, this also fixed the issue
{
  "packageManager": "npm@10.5.2",
  "overrides": {
    "react": "$react",
    "react-dom": "$react-dom"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "again": "^0.0.1",
    "next": "15.0.1",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.25",
    "react": "19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021"
  }
}

You can check this GitHub link for more information https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/72204
